# JavaScript, a loop for asking a specific answer

Tags: javascript

I want the user to input a number between 1-100, until the user inputs a valid number, the loop will keep saying "That input is invalid".

My code is below.  Where did I go wrong?

```
// Initialize var userGuess
var userGuess;

// I want to make the prompt keep asking a number between 1-100, if it doesn't satisfy the requirement, it will keep asking
for (var valid = false; valid == true;) {
    userGuess = prompt("Guess a number");
    if ((userGuess >= 1) && (userGuess <= 100)) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
        console.log("That number is invalid! Please enter a number between 1-100");
    }
}
```

Comment: _until I get a specific answer_: You are not checking this at all

Answer (score 5):

```
// Initialize var userGuess
var userGuess;

// I want to make the prompt keep asking a number between 1-100, if it doesn't satisfy the requirement, it will keep asking
var valid = false;
while(!valid){
    userGuess = prompt("Guess a number");
    if ((userGuess >= 1) && (userGuess <= 100)) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        console.log("That number is invalid! Please enter a number between 1-100");
    }
}


// Initialize var userGuess
var userGuess;
```

With a for loop

```
// I want to make the prompt keep asking a number between 1-100, if it doesn't satisfy the requirement, it will keep asking
for(var valid = false; !valid){
    userGuess = prompt("Guess a number");
    if ((userGuess >= 1) && (userGuess <= 100)) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        console.log("That number is invalid! Please enter a number between 1-100");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rafalio!

Is there any way to make this to a for loop? I want this to use for loop because I want to avoid declaring a global variable as much as I can.

Comment: @user122652 A for loop doesn't make sense in this instance because you don't know how many times you want to loop through beforehand.

Comment: If you really insist on a for loop, i updated the answer. But a while loop makes more sense, use for loops when you iterate over something, a collection for example, when you know beforehand how many things you are iterating through.

Comment: @user122652 global variables? there is zero difference! I think you need to review scoping.

Comment: I see where I went wrong.  The conditional that I made was wrong!

Comment: loops is loops, doesn't matter if you use `for` or `while`, you can accomplish the same exact goal with either, every time, with no functional difference at all, just structural/syntactical differences.  `for` is syntactically suited for iterating over a collection, `while` is more syntactically suited for what you're doing, looping until a condition changes not related to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, In your scenario of trying to capture a valid user input, I would be more inclined to use a recursive function call.

```
function userValue(){
    var guess = prompt("Guess a number")
    if(guess > 0 && guess <= 100){
         return guess; 
    }

    return userValue();
}

var value = userValue();
```

I have made a few applications with this method. Its your call.

W

Comment: No problem, Anytime :)